# iOS video not playing (play button crossed out)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to play a video from URL, but when I run the code, all I can see is the play button crossed out.

here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit 
class ViewController: UIViewController {   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        let videoURL = URL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerControler = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerControler.player = player
        present(playerControler, animated: true) {
        player.play()

    }

}
```

Xcode 9.1
Swift 4

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the view in the storyboard? If so, please check that and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your `.plist` file to be able to get video by given `http` URL

`App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

Add this code to your `.plist` `xml`, or simply try to load `https:` video:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```